String Slicing in Tosca
How do I extract a substring from a string based on index in Tosca? For example if I have a 20 character code, I want to extract the last 10 characters from it.
I've tried looking into regular expressions for the same but I couldn't find any results online.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

@Community For someone who knows TOSCA this is enough information to answer the question.

Try using tbox partial buffer. Using that you can split the string

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

@Community For someone who actually knows TOSCA " tbox partial buffer" is the needed search term to find the needed information in the official TOSCA Dokumentation: https://documentation.tricentis.com/tosca/2320/en/content/standard_subset/automation_tools/buffer_operations.htm#partialbuffer

There are several ways to achieve this:

As others have said, use a partial buffer (TBox Partial Buffer), with the Last parameter set to 10 and use ActionMode Input. See also TBox Partial Buffer in the Tosca documentation.

Use a regular expression to extract to a buffer:
{REGEX[".*(?<Last10Chars>.{10})"]}

This will extract the last 10 characters to the buffer Last10Chars.
(You may need to include the start and end anchors (^ and $) at the beginning and end of the expression, and this assumes no spurious whitespace which you might have when automating a web application.)
Use ActionMode Verify. See also Extracting text using regular expressions in the Tosca documentation.

Use Excel engine functions (this may depend on your Excel language configuration, I'm assuming English):
{CALC[RIGHT(""""{B[SourceValue]"""", 10)]}

This assumes you already have the source value in a buffer called SourceValue.
See also Perform calculations in the Tosca documentation.


I'm pretty new to Tosca myself, so I may have missed other options for this.
